# In MySQL full-text search, how to search for documents that ONLY contain the specific words?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match

I have table with titles and I only want to find that titles composed ENTIRELY of a subset of words.

For example,

```
SELECT title
FROM my_titles_table WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3 ... wordN' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

I want to find all titles that are composed of word1 word2 word3 ... wordN or a subset of them, but no other word.

For instance, if my query is "how to train your dragon" as my words, then I would like to find titles like "dragon" or "train your dragon" or "your dragon to train" but not "dungeons and dragons" because the word "dungeon" is not in my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this functionality is supported by full text search.  In fact, it is hard to figure out a brute force way to do this.

Here is one brute force method:

```
where trim(replace(replace(replace(title, $word1, ''), $word2), ''), $word3, '')) = ''
```

This isn't exactly perfect, because "pine apple" will match "pine apple".

Hmmmm . . . There is another alternative with regular expressions:

```
 where title like concat('^(', replace('word1 word2 word3', ' ', '|'),
                          '[ ]*)+$)
```

That is, the match has to start at the beginning and end of the string and the intervening words must all match.

There isn't a way to speed up such a query, as far as I know.